# choices combination,order & tree

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have following data that represents sequence of person's choice between four values (f1,f2,c1,c2) :

```
df=structure(list(combi = structure(c(24L, 8L, 3L, 19L, 4L, 23L, 
15L, 12L, 14L, 22L, 5L, 13L, 18L, 9L, 2L, 25L, 11L, 7L, 21L, 
10L, 6L, 17L, 20L, 16L), .Label = c("", "c1-c2-f1-f2", "c1-c2-f2-f1", 
"c1-f1-c2-f2", "c1-f1-f2-c2", "c1-f2-c2-f1", "c1-f2-f1-c2", "c2-c1-f1-f2", 
"c2-c1-f2-f1", "c2-f1-c1-f2", "c2-f1-f2-c1", "c2-f2-c1-f1", "c2-f2-f1-c1", 
"f1-c1-c2-f2", "f1-c1-f2-c2", "f1-c2-c1-f2", "f1-c2-f2-c1", "f1-f2-c1-c2", 
"f1-f2-c2-c1", "f2-c1-c2-f1", "f2-c1-f1-c2", "f2-c2-c1-f1", "f2-c2-f1-c1", 
"f2-f1-c1-c2", "f2-f1-c2-c1"), class = "factor"), nb = c(10L, 
0L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 18L, 
5L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 11L, 2L)), .Names = c("combi", "nb"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 
3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 
29L, 31L, 33L, 35L, 37L, 39L, 41L, 43L, 45L, 47L))
```

I'm wondering if there's tree representation (or else) that could quantifiy, for each step choices number, by taking in account sub chain that are commun. Example :

```
f2  (52) -f1 (28)  -c1-c2  (10)
                   -c2-c1  (18)
```

f2(52) there is 52 times chains begining by f2. there is 28 times chain beginning by f2-f1.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the `combi` values in (using `as.character`) you can expand those values to character columns:

```
df2 <-  cbind(df, read.table(text=as.character(df$combi), sep="-",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)  )
```

Then you can tabulate at whatever level you want:

```
 xtabs(nb~V1, data=df2) # First level only
#V1
#c1 c2 f1 f2 
#10 12 15 52 

xtabs(nb~paste(V1,V2,sep="-"), data=df2) # first and second
#--
# paste(V1, V2, sep = "-")
#c1-c2 c1-f1 c1-f2 c2-c1 c2-f1 c2-f2 f1-c1 f1-c2 f1-f2 f2-c1 f2-c2 f2-f1 
#    2     2     6     5     5     2     2     6     7    16     8    28
```

You can also deploy the `addmargins` function to compactly the display the two "most senior" position sub-totals:

```
 addmargins( xtabs(nb~V1+V2, data=df2))
 #=========
     V2
V1    c1 c2 f1 f2 Sum
  c1   0  2  2  6  10
  c2   5  0  5  2  12
  f1   2  6  0  7  15
  f2  16  8 28  0  52
  Sum 23 16 35 15  89
```

This could be "flattened" with `ftable`:

```
 ftable( addmargins( xtabs(nb~V1+V2, data=df2)), row.vars=1:2)
V1  V2     
c1  c1    0
    c2    2
    f1    2
    f2    6
    Sum  10
c2  c1    5
    c2    0
    f1    5
    f2    2
    Sum  12
f1  c1    2
    c2    6
    f1    0
    f2    7
    Sum  15
f2  c1   16
    c2    8
    f1   28
    f2    0
    Sum  52
Sum c1   23
    c2   16
    f1   35
    f2   15
    Sum  89
```

And the final tally would be:

```
xtabs(nb~paste(V1,V2,V3,V4,sep="-"), data=df2)
#-----
paste(V1, V2, V3, V4, sep = "-")
c1-c2-f1-f2 c1-c2-f2-f1 c1-f1-c2-f2 c1-f1-f2-c2 c1-f2-c2-f1 c1-f2-f1-c2 c2-c1-f1-f2 c2-c1-f2-f1 
          0           2           1           1           4           2           0           5 
c2-f1-c1-f2 c2-f1-f2-c1 c2-f2-c1-f1 c2-f2-f1-c1 f1-c1-c2-f2 f1-c1-f2-c2 f1-c2-c1-f2 f1-c2-f2-c1 
          0           5           2           0           1           1           2           4 
f1-f2-c1-c2 f1-f2-c2-c1 f2-c1-c2-f1 f2-c1-f1-c2 f2-c2-c1-f1 f2-c2-f1-c1 f2-f1-c1-c2 f2-f1-c2-c1 
          3           4          11           5           3           5          10          18
```

To see it all in a column:

```
as.matrix( xtabs(nb~paste(V1,V2,V3,V4,sep="-"), data=df2) )
#----------------
            [,1]
c1-c2-f1-f2    0
c1-c2-f2-f1    2
c1-f1-c2-f2    1
c1-f1-f2-c2    1
c1-f2-c2-f1    4
c1-f2-f1-c2    2
c2-c1-f1-f2    0
c2-c1-f2-f1    5
c2-f1-c1-f2    0
c2-f1-f2-c1    5
c2-f2-c1-f1    2
c2-f2-f1-c1    0
f1-c1-c2-f2    1
f1-c1-f2-c2    1
f1-c2-c1-f2    2
f1-c2-f2-c1    4
f1-f2-c1-c2    3
f1-f2-c2-c1    4
f2-c1-c2-f1   11
f2-c1-f1-c2    5
f2-c2-c1-f1    3
f2-c2-f1-c1    5
f2-f1-c1-c2   10
f2-f1-c2-c1   18
```

I suppose a "final answer with all the subtotals might be:

```
 ftable( addmargins( xtabs(nb~V1+V2+paste(V3,V4,sep="-"), data=df2)), row.vars=1:3)
```

However, that has so many zero entries that I hesitate to recommend. You could strip out zero rows:

```
my.ftable <- ftable( addmargins( xtabs(nb~V1+V2+paste(V3,V4,sep="-"), data=df2)), row.vars=1:3)
my.df.table <- as.data.frame(my.ftable)
names(my.df.table)[3] <- "3rd_4th"
my.df.table[ my.df.table$Freq > 0,  ]
#---------
     V1  V2 3rd_4th Freq
14   f2  f1   c1-c2   10
15  Sum  f1   c1-c2   10
18   f1  f2   c1-c2    3
20  Sum  f2   c1-c2    3
23   f1 Sum   c1-c2    3
24   f2 Sum   c1-c2   10
25  Sum Sum   c1-c2   13
34   f2  c2   c1-f1    3
35  Sum  c2   c1-f1    3
42   c2  f2   c1-f1    2
45  Sum  f2   c1-f1    2
47   c2 Sum   c1-f1    2
49   f2 Sum   c1-f1    3
50  Sum Sum   c1-f1    5
# and many more rows
#...  until
321  c1 Sum     Sum   10
322  c2 Sum     Sum   12
323  f1 Sum     Sum   15
324  f2 Sum     Sum   52
325 Sum Sum     Sum   89
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not exactly what you mean by a "tree structure" but this gives you the numbers
in a table using base R. It should be easy to format that as you like from this result.

```r
df=structure(list(combi = structure(c(24L, 8L, 3L, 19L, 4L, 23L, 
15L, 12L, 14L, 22L, 5L, 13L, 18L, 9L, 2L, 25L, 11L, 7L, 21L, 
10L, 6L, 17L, 20L, 16L), .Label = c("", "c1-c2-f1-f2", "c1-c2-f2-f1", 
"c1-f1-c2-f2", "c1-f1-f2-c2", "c1-f2-c2-f1", "c1-f2-f1-c2", "c2-c1-f1-f2", 
"c2-c1-f2-f1", "c2-f1-c1-f2", "c2-f1-f2-c1", "c2-f2-c1-f1", "c2-f2-f1-c1", 
"f1-c1-c2-f2", "f1-c1-f2-c2", "f1-c2-c1-f2", "f1-c2-f2-c1", "f1-f2-c1-c2", 
"f1-f2-c2-c1", "f2-c1-c2-f1", "f2-c1-f1-c2", "f2-c2-c1-f1", "f2-c2-f1-c1", 
"f2-f1-c1-c2", "f2-f1-c2-c1"), class = "factor"), nb = c(10L, 
0L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 18L, 
5L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 11L, 2L)), .Names = c("combi", "nb"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 
3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 
29L, 31L, 33L, 35L, 37L, 39L, 41L, 43L, 45L, 47L))


tmp <- sapply(as.character(df$combi), strsplit, split = "-")
tmp <- do.call(rbind, tmp)
colnames(tmp) <- paste0("str", 1:4)
rownames(tmp) <- NULL
tmp <- data.frame(df, tmp)

tmp$str3 <- paste(tmp$str3, tmp$str4, sep = "-")

str1 <- aggregate(list(nb_str1 = tmp[,"nb"]), tmp["str1"], sum)
str2 <- aggregate(list(nb_str2 = tmp[,"nb"]), tmp[c("str1", "str2")], sum)
str3 <- aggregate(list(nb_str3 = tmp[,"nb"]), tmp[c("str1", "str2", "str3")], sum)

tmp <- merge(str3, str1)
tmp <- merge(tmp, str2)

tmp <- tmp[, c("str1", "nb_str1", "str2", "nb_str2", "str3", "nb_str3")]
tmp
#>    str1 nb_str1 str2 nb_str2  str3 nb_str3
#> 1    c1      10   c2       2 f1-f2       0
#> 2    c1      10   c2       2 f2-f1       2
#> 3    c1      10   f1       2 c2-f2       1
#> 4    c1      10   f1       2 f2-c2       1
#> 5    c1      10   f2       6 c2-f1       4
#> 6    c1      10   f2       6 f1-c2       2
#> 7    c2      12   c1       5 f1-f2       0
#> 8    c2      12   c1       5 f2-f1       5
#> 9    c2      12   f1       5 c1-f2       0
#> 10   c2      12   f1       5 f2-c1       5
#> 11   c2      12   f2       2 c1-f1       2
#> 12   c2      12   f2       2 f1-c1       0
#> 13   f1      15   c1       2 c2-f2       1
#> 14   f1      15   c1       2 f2-c2       1
#> 15   f1      15   c2       6 c1-f2       2
#> 16   f1      15   c2       6 f2-c1       4
#> 17   f1      15   f2       7 c1-c2       3
#> 18   f1      15   f2       7 c2-c1       4
#> 19   f2      52   c1      16 c2-f1      11
#> 20   f2      52   c1      16 f1-c2       5
#> 21   f2      52   c2       8 c1-f1       3
#> 22   f2      52   c2       8 f1-c1       5
#> 23   f2      52   f1      28 c1-c2      10
#> 24   f2      52   f1      28 c2-c1      18
```

Created on 2018-03-15 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 4):

The [`data.tree` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html#introduction) specialises in tree representation. It is based on splitting variables in a hierarchal order, for example world -> continent -> country -> city. In your case, you've mentioned every order for `c1`, `c2`, `f1` and `f2`. Likely you'd need to do four tree plots e.g. c1 --> either c2, f1 or f2, each leading to the two unused values, and then plot them.

A basic example starting with c1, and then splitting off, and not including specific values:

```
library(data.tree)
c1 <- Node$new("c1")      # 1st level chain, "c1"
c2 <- c1$AddChild("c2")   # new 2nd level chain, "c2", off c1
f1 <- c2$AddChild("f1-f2")   # new level off c2
f2 <- c2$AddChild("f2-f1")   # new level off c2
f1 <- c1$AddChild("f1")   # new 2nd level chain, "f1", off c1
c2 <- f1$AddChild("c2-f2")   # new level off f1
f2 <- f1$AddChild("f2-c2")   # new level off f1
f2 <- c1$AddChild("f2")   # new 2nd level chain, "f2", off c1
c2 <- f2$AddChild("c2-f1")   # new level off f2
f1 <- f2$AddChild("f1-c2")   # new level off f2

print(c1)
       levelName
1  c1           
2   ¦--c2       
3   ¦   ¦--f1-f2
4   ¦   °--f2-f1
5   ¦--f1       
6   ¦   ¦--c2-f2
7   ¦   °--f2-c2
8   °--f2       
9       ¦--c2-f1
10      °--f1-c2

plot(c1)
```

[image]